# MySql query to fetch results from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to fetch total retailers from retailer table and other attributes from visit info table. This query is giving correct result for total retailers and visited retailers but giving an incorrect result for feedback count, promise order count etc two columns.

```
select count(distinctrow tbl_retailer.retailer_id) as total_retailers,count(distinctrow tbl_visit_info.retailer_id) as visited_retailers,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 1 ,1,0)) AS feedback,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 2 ,1,0)) AS promise_order,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 3 ,1,0)) AS stock,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 6 ,1,0)) AS payment
from tbl_visit_info,tbl_retailer 
where visitor_id=175 and tbl_retailer.sr_id=175;
```

[This is my retailer table from which I want to count total retailers from this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ3GA.png)

[This is my visit_info table from which I want to count visited_retailers, feedback count, Promise_order_count_stock_count and payment count which are defined as in activity_type column in visit_info table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPeQQ.png)

Comment: You need to give sample table data, expected output and what is your current query returning, before we can figure out

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: By using joins is doesn't work. It is giving the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two sub-queries, one for each table. `JOIN` the results.

```
select * from

(select sr_id, count(distinctrow retailer_id) as total_retailers
 from tbl_retailer 
 group by sr_id) tr

join

(select visitor_id,
        count(distinctrow retailer_id) as visited_retailers,
        SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 1 ,1,0)) AS feedback,
        SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 2 ,1,0)) AS promise_order,
        SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 3 ,1,0)) AS stock,
        SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 6 ,1,0)) AS payment
 from tbl_visit_info
 group by visitor_id) tvi

on tvi.visitor_id = tr.sr_id
where tvi.visitor_id = 175
```

Simply remove the `WHERE` clause to get info about all visitors!

BTW, `distinctrow` is probably not needed here.

Comment: Dear now if am using date in where clause it is not returning any result

Comment: Add a WHERE clause with date condition to each sub-query.

Comment: date_format(tbl_visit_info.date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-07-02' AND '2018-08-37';   I have added this but it is giving an error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'tbl_visit_info.date' in 'where clause'

Comment: Well, since I don't know your data model, I can only guess. Perhaps that WHERE clause is only needed in the 2:nd sub-query (the tbl_visit_info one.)?